# How to setup a php version to 2 different laravel Project?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, wamp

Hello I have 2 Laravel Projects one is installed inside the `xamp/htdocs` directory and the other is installed in the `wamp/www` directory. the php version on xamp project is <8.0 and the other projects runs on an older version 7.2

How do I set xamp to run on a newer version of php and wamp on an older version of php ?

Thank you in Advance

I have tried to move the xamp project to wamp/www and set the php version to a newer version[image: php version set to a newer version]
but when I type in the terminal inside the project php -v [image: php version]

Comment: WampServer can easily switch PHP version, so as long as you dont want to run both sites at the same time get rid of XAMPP and move the project to WAMSPerver. See Virtual Hosts

Comment: The latest version of WAMPServer comes with a FCGI implementation, so if you do want to run both sites at the same time, you can use that and have different versions of PHP running in each Virtual Host

Answer (score 2):

i recommend you the software called laragon, it comes with a wonderfull project managment for laravel and you can easily swith php versions

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use laravel's homestead: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/homestead

You can set up multiple projects with different php versions